# How to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS to 16.10

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, 16.10, usb-installation

I have ISO copy of Ubuntu 16.10 Desktop (64-bit).

Please help me with the steps to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS to 16.10 (Yakkety Yak) *without loosing any data*.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10 as follow:

> To upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 from the current LTS you will need to tell the OS that you want to receive non-LTS updates.

1. Open ‘Software & Updates’ using the Unity Dash
2. Select the ‘Updates‘ tab
3. Find the section titled ‘Notify me of a new Ubuntu version‘
4. Change this from ‘For long-term support versions’ to ‘For any new
   version‘
5. Click ‘Close’

You’ll instantly be prompted to run a quick update.

[Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/10/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-10)

Comment: Dear, I have ISO file. Don't want to re-download. Looking for upgrade with the downloaded copy that I have of 16.10